# How to save the data of an ArrayList for an app even after closing app?

Tags: android, arraylist

I have developed an app, and right now I have an arraylist of Profiles (Custom class) that I would like to be saved whenever a new profile is added to the app. So, whenever a user adds a profile, after closing and re-opening the app, the profiles are still there. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to make data persist from one session to another i.e. turning the app on and off? If yes, you'll need to incorporate some type of storage such as Sqlite or the local storage available on the device, like shared preferences. See here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I prefer to use local storage using Shared Preferences, however, all the solutions I found where for storing arraylist of strings and NOT a custom class like my case.

Comment: for saving arrayList check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11050845/7569106

Comment: @MohamedEmbaby as I have mentioned, this solution works for ArrayList of type string, not a custom object.

Comment: As far as I know there is no such thing. However its better to make some adjustment to ur app and use Database like sqlite

Comment: Hmm, I see, ill keep the question open for other suggestions, until then, ill learn how to use SQLite to solve me issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution by using Gson from [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcliHGR3CHo)